# Check if array contains values which are the same

Tags: actionscript-3

How can i check if two or more values in the same array are the same?

just looking for an explanation thanks

Comment: Is the value known? Do you need to know what the duplicates are? Or do you literally just need to know if there are any duplicates in the array, ie true or false?

Comment: Well you can use `indexOf(value) != -1` to check if a value already exists in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to check if any value exists twice:

```
function hasDuplicate(array:Array):Boolean {
    var keys:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    for each(var item:* in array){
        if(keys[item])
            return true;
        keys[item] = true;
    }
    return false;
}

trace(hasDuplicate(["a", "b", "c"])); // false
trace(hasDuplicate(["a", "b", "c", "b"])); // true
```

This works by looping through all values using `for each`, then storing each value as a key in a `Dictionary`. If any value already has a key in the dictionary, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't wrote on AS 3 for a couple of years but answer may looks something like this:

```
function hasSame(arr:Array):Boolean {
    arr = arr.concat().sort();
    var prev  = null;
    for each (var a in arr) {
        if (prev != null && a == prev) {
            return true;
        }
        prev = a;
    } 
    return false;
}
```